What's this episode in the Pokémon anime and why wasn't Pikachu with ash?
I was watching Pokémon battles and I watched this



What episode was it? And why didn't ash use Pikachu?

What episode was it?
The video you shared is the opening battle of the Johto league silver conference victory tournament between Ash Ketchum and Gary Oak. 
This battle between them is not covered in a single episode. The battle starts in episode The Ties That Bind and ends in Can't Beat the Heat which are the 7th and 8th episodes of season 6. 
Why didn't Ash use Pikachu?
Ash knows that the opponent who is battling in the next is Gary Oak. Ash takes this match seriously and does research on Gary's Pokémon all night. This is shown in the episode before the battle starts. Ash knows that Gary had a wide variety of evolved Pokémon. 

Misty: Have you been online all night?
Ash: Yep (Misty shocks)

After some words between Misty and Brock, Ash shows Misty Gary's page.

Ash: See this is Gary's page. 

During breakfast, they discuss which Pokémon to use.  

Brock: Gary's got all the kinds. He doesn't really favour one kind. 
Misty: All different types!? He is really a chip off the old oak block1.
Brock: Not only that. They are all first class (i.e. evolved) and in tiptop shape. So he must have rotated them a lot.
Ash: Yes. He did. He has been that way for as long I've known the guy. 
Brock: And since he doesn't prefer a single type, putting your team together is crucial.

If you look at the list of Pokemon Gary owned, many of them are evolved Pokémon and are very strong against electrical Pokémon and especially Pikachu (since it is not evolved). 
Pokémons used by Gary in the match are:

Nidoqueen
Magmar 
Blastoise
Arcanine
Scizor
Golem

All these Pokémon are experienced. Pikachu's electrical effects don't have much effect on Nidoqueen and Golem as they are Ground type Pokémon. Scizor is much faster than Pikachu and can dodge his electrical effects easily. Blastoise has been travelling with Gary since he started battling and is very experienced. Moreover it is physically stronger than Pikachu. A skull bash attack or water gun attack of Blastoise would do the trick for Gary if Ash used it.
Ash knows he should compose his team with different kinds of Pokemon to win over Gary. So he selects different kinds of Pokemon. To bring diversity in the team, Brock calls Liza and asks to send Charizard for the tournament.
Why wasn't Pikachu with Ash?
Pikachu was not registered for this battle. During the break, Pikachu tells Ash that he is ready for the battle and wants to fight. But Ash denies him because he is not allowed to fight with Pokémon which are not registered before the match. 

1. Here she is referring to Gary's grand father Professor Oak who is a Pokemon researcher and has all the Pokémon.

This is mostly episode 269 and 270 of the original series. Ash vs Gary in opening battle of the Johto League Silver Conference Victory Tournament. 
Ash doesn't use Pikachu because he spent part of the first episode researching Gary and his pokemon. Based on what he learns,  he chooses a team of high level pokemon best suited to fight Gary's pokemon. Pikachu didn't make the cut. Based on the line up,  it was a good choice. Too many earth pokemon would make Pikachu useless.
